# else path not taken in unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-coverage

I am working on angular 6

> I don't have any  else statement in my below code.But I am unable to cover branches due to else path not taken .What I need to do to get 100% branch coverage in this case?

```
 getHeaderDocumentList(documents: any) {
            if (documents) {
                documents.result.docAttachment.forEach(element => {
                    this.headerdocumentdetails.push(element.DocumentUniqueID);
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try passing an input that evaluates false to the if statement and bypasses it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to get full coverage reported, the code needs to eventually hit the (here non-explicitly-existent) `else`-path. For that matter pass in a `falsy` parameter like ``` 0 | false | undefined | null | NaN | '' | "" | `` ``` as in

```
component.getHeaderDocumentList(false);
expect(false).toEqual(false); // This line is optional. Most test suites require some kind of assertion in each test.
```

Now your test-suite should report both branches as covered.

> Last solution would be to add `/* istanbul ignore else */` in before the if case. That will tell the coverage reporter to effectively ignore the else path

Comment: Good Idea! But some case I am unable to fix this. Any way as of now 80% is enough. And one more question: did you heard anything about [sourceMap:true](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/271)

Comment: Hm,that is rather weird. It should stop complaining once you ran the tests again.

Comment: Last solution would be to add `/* istanbul ignore else */` in before the if case. That will tell the coverage reporter to effectively ignore the else path.

Comment: If the expected output of a false/empty document list is that `headerdocumentdetails` does not change, that is a valid test.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `/* istanbul ignore else */` before `if` statement which do not have `else` part. Coverage reporter will ignore the else path.